# How Would One Find a Dependency-Order list of Tables to Delete for Test Data?

Tags: sql, hibernate, annotations, foreign-keys, hibernate-annotations

I have a test suite that needs to delete any existing data in my local MySQL test instance for a large number (but not all) of the tables in the system.

```
 delete from customer;
```

Of course, `customer` has quite a few foreign keys to it, so I also have to delete a few more tables...

```
 delete from customer_email;
 delete from customer_phone;
```

And again, these tables have more foreign keys...

```
 delete from customer_email_notification;
 delete from customer_phone_call;
```

etc etc ad nauseum. It's frustrating to have to mentally navigate the entire data model in order to write the test setup.

I am using Hibernate so I was wondering if there was some way to automatically get a priority-order list of tables such that it can be passed directly to  a deletion handler. Ideally:

```
 List<String> dependentTables = foreignKeyGraph.findAll("customer");
 deletionHandler.clean(dependentTables);
```

Is there a Hibernate utility out there that can do this? I was going to write something that traversed our domain's annotations and derived table names that way, but it seems like a lot of work for a fairly common problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good way to handle this is to use DELETE triggers on each table.  On the CUSTOMER table there would be a trigger to delete all the related data found by following each foreign key that relates back to CUSTOMER for the given CUSTOMER_ID - likewise for each table related to CUSTOMER - and each table related to those tables, etc.  So for example, if the CUSTOMER_EMAIL table relates back to CUSTOMER via CUSTOMER_ID, and likewise CUSTOMER_PHONE, then the delete trigger on CUSTOMER might look like

```
CREATE TRIGGER CUSTOMER_AD  -- AD = After Delete
  AFTER DELETE ON CUSTOMER
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM CUSTOMER_EMAIL E WHERE E.CUSTOMER_ID = :NEW.CUSTOMER_ID;
  DELETE FROM CUSTOMER_PHONE P WHERE P.CUSTOMER_ID = :NEW.CUSTOMER_ID;
END CUSTOMER_AD;
```

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Yup this would definitely work. I'm interested in something that doesn't require hand writing them all out (unless absolutely necessary).